# Not getting user auth status in component only if redirected

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have my dasboard component, which works fine, showing the user auth.uid, and the projects fetched from firestore. See below the line `//if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/signin'/>` which makes the component not work properly when uncommented.

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import Notifications from './notifications';
import ProjectList from '../projects/projectList';
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { RootState } from '../../store/reducers/rootReducer';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
  console.log("dashboard")
  console.log(state)
  return {
    projects: state.firestore.ordered.projects,
    auth: state.firebase.auth
  } 
}

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps);
type Props = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

class Dashboard extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    console.log("component");
    console.log(this.props);

    const { projects, auth } = this.props;
    console.log("component projects");
    console.log(projects);

    console.log("component uid");
    console.log(auth.uid);

    //if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/signin'/>  THIS IS THE LINE THAT CHANGES THE BEHAVIOUR.
    return (
      <div className="dashboard container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s12 m6">
          <ProjectList projects={this.props.projects}/>
            </div>
          <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
          <Notifications />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default compose<React.FunctionComponent>(
  connector,
  firestoreConnect([
    { collection: 'projects' }
  ])
)(Dashboard);
```

These are the logs I obtain in the console. Many if them with the projects undefined at the beginning, until the authStatus changes and the firestoreConnects high order component fetches the projects I guess. So far, apart from the too many calls stuff which I believe is normal, everything is fine.

[image]

I also got my app listening to the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
          <App />
        </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
});
```

However, if I uncomment the `//if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/signin'/>` I do not get neither the auth.uid, nor the projects, and the console.logs show this, even if the user is logged in.

[image]

I expected that with the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` to the auth status and with the `firestoreConnect` to the project collection, the component would also update, but it redirects you to the sign in page because the `auth.uid` inside the incommented if: `//if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/signin'/>` is undefined and the component does not get re-rendered again.

I yet would not like to share a codeSandbox project to avoid sharing my firebase config, which would be needed to replicate all the authStatusChanged and project collectionChanged subscription stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I found the issue. I had an html hyperlink tag to go to my home link like this:

`<a href="/" className="Whatever">HomePageButtonName</a>`

I replaced that with:

`<Link to='/' className="Whatever">HomePageButtonName</Link>`

previous `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';` and that solved the problem.

Guess that when I was going back to the home page, it was not through the react link, so the props where not being updated.